# Problem with installing Zend Framework and using zf script

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, zend-server

I have install ZendFramewrok with instruction on: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html and when I try to run command like

```
php -i
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/php: line 2: /bin: Is a directory
/usr/bin/php: line 3: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 4: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 5: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 6: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 7: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 8: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 9: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 10: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 11: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 12: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 13: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 14: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 15: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 16: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 17: Desktop: command not found
/usr/bin/php: line 18: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/php: line 18: ` * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2005-2011 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)'
```

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. Does anyone know what can be the problem?

Comment: How did you install php? What happens when you do `head /usr/bin/php`?

Comment: Install with: apt-get install php5. After that I install zend-framework-bin. Head command return: <?php
/**
 * Zend Framework
 *
 * LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the new BSD license that is bundled
 * with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd

Comment: afaik `php5` doesn't include the cli executable. Try `apt-get install php5-cli`

Comment: lol @answers who copied my last comment to whore points

Comment: @Mike B, are you  sure? My answer was before your concrete comment. And my answer was about reinstall -- not about concrete way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shandu, I think your current PHP install is broken. ZF isn't a source, as just simple `php -i` is a base key.

Try to reinstall PHP somehow to get normal default result of `php -i`

Comment: Thanks. This is it. I need to reinstall php5-cli

Answer (score -1):

php-cli is missing. on ubuntu install it via

- sudo apt-get install php5-cli